# Solution of Triangles ; is any case ambiguous?

Tags: trigonometry

EDIT1:

The "ambiguous case" of Elementary Trigonometry is discussed. The case arises we are told in text-books that when two sides and a non-included angle is given to solve, there are two possibilities.

Law of Sines and Cosines used to derive in brief ( when *a, b, A* are given ) :

$$\frac{a}{\sin A}=\frac{b}{\sin B} ;\; A+B+C= \pi ; \tag1$$

$$ \cos C= \frac {b}{a} \sin^2A -\cos A \sqrt{1-\left(\frac {b}{a} \sin A\right)^2}\tag2$$

$$ c^2= a^2+ b^2 \cos 2A + 2 b\cos A \sqrt{a^2-\left({b} \sin A\right)^2} \tag3 $$

If in front of radical sign $\pm$ is included it would give rise to an ambiguity.

However if we stick to the ***same/consistent convention of positive sign for square root*** throughout and check for each of the two given example SSA cases

$$( a=7; b=3; A= 120^{\circ} \to c=5 ) \tag 4$$

$$( a=7; b=3; A= 60^{\circ} \to c=8 )\tag 5,$$

then there is ***no ambiguity*** at all, and (3) holds good always, it is also confirmed by the construction with the relevant choice shown below:

[image]

Please comment about the view.

Comment: Consider a similar example but with $a < b$, e.g. $a = 2.75, b = 3, A = 60^\circ$.

Comment: So you mean that only if a> b, the formula (3) applies singly  without any ambiguity  but, when a<b we have  both $+$ and $-$ in (3) making it ambiguous or double valued.. right ?

Comment: @Narasimham: When $a>b$, we discard one ostensible solution, as the given angle would be *external* to the corresponding triangle; likewise, in the $a=b$ case, we discard the degenerate solution for which the sides coincide. So, those cases are naturally unambiguous. When $b>a>b\sin A$, we have two valid solutions; for $a=b\sin A$, "one" (double-)solution: the choices coincide because the square root vanishes; and for $a<b\sin A$, *no* solutions: the triangle can't close (the square root is imaginary).

Comment: Thanks. when $a>b,$ angle  $A$ in equations  (4),(5) are both *internal* and  satisfy the same equation (3).